# For which regular $n$-gons are there two sides/diagonals with a rational ratio other than $1$?

Tags: polygons, algebraic-numbers

**Context:** I'm trying to see which regular polygons can be built using points generated from a wallpaper group. I know that if a regular polygon has more than a certain amount of these vertices, some pairs of them will have to be related by a translation. If these pairs form certain impossible angles, I can arrive at a contradiction. However, these pairs can end up parallel, in which case I'm forced to answer the question in the title (copied below for convenience).

**Question:** For which regular $n$-gons are there two sides/diagonals with a rational ratio other than $1$?

From [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3051186/718671), which takes care of the specific case side to diagonal, I can guess that answering this question will involve some knowledge on algebraic numbers, which I unfortunately lack. I know that regular hexagons have the aforementioned property (since their side to longest diagonal ratio equals $2$), so that all regular $6n$-gons have the same property too. But other than that, I'm completely lost on what to do.

**EDIT:** Meant rational, not integral. I hope this isn't an issue.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/519115/15624

Comment: @AngelaRichardson Do you know if this argument could be adapted to my more general case? Alternatively, do you know where I could read the necessary theory to understand that solution?

Comment: I'm don't know how to adapt the argument to the more general case. For an accessible introduction to Galois groups, I would recommend reading https://nrich.maths.org/1422.